# UIBezierPath - draw multiple rects for a single path

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I can draw a single rect with :

```
let roundedRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 50)
```

with this I can not add a new rect to the same path. (I need multiple rects to a single layer)

I can also just draw a rect by moving the point :

```
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x:point1.x-rectWidth/2.0,y:point1.y) )
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point1.x-rectWidth/2.0, y: point2.y))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point1.x+rectWidth/2.0, y: point2.y))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point1.x+rectWidth/2.0, y: point1.y))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:point1.x-rectWidth/2.0,y:point1.y))
```

which will not be a rounded rect.

Which approach can I use to get a rounded rect ?

Comment: Why not create multiple `CAShapeLayers`? Like views, layers have sublayers.

Comment: @dfd, the OP never said anything about layers. We don't know if that's what they're doing with their paths.

Comment: @DuncanC The question states *"I need multiple rects to a single layer"*.

Comment: So it does. I missed that bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building a rounded rect yourself is somewhat tricky. I suggest creating rounded rect paths using the UIBezierPath initializer `init(roundedRect:cornerRadius:)`

You can use `append(_:)` to append rounded rect paths to another path:

```
var path = UIBezierPath() //Create an empty path

//Add a rounded rect to the path
path.append(UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect1, cornerRadius: radius1))

//Add another rounded rect to the path
path.append(UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect2, cornerRadius: radius2))

//Lather, rinse, repeat.
path.append(UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect3, cornerRadius: radius3))
```

### Edit:

To animate all of your rectangles drawing from the bottom, like an ink-jet printer, create a CAShapeLayer that's the same size as your view, install a zero-height rectangle at the bottom, and make that layer the mask layer for your view's layer. Then create a CABasicAnimation of the rectangle growing to the full height of the view.

Comment: So you create multiple instances of a bezier, and extract their paths to a single one. Is it ok with performance (maybe dumb to ask)

Comment: @Curnelious performance-wise which part are you worried about?

Comment: Thanks, with this I can not find a way to animate it. Do you know maybe how to animate the drawing from the bottom ? could make it work with CBAnimation

Comment: What sort of animation do you want? Drawing one rect at a time, and drawing each rect instantly? Or do you want to "paint" up from the bottom, like an ink-jet printer?

Comment: @DuncanC drawing all of them at once from the bottom , the animation won't work no matter what I tried

Comment: See the edit to my answer. You could use a mask layer with a rectangle shape that grows from zero height to the full height of the view.